# How can I disable the key in second time press same in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events, keydown

When press first time 37 it showing alert message, again press the same key second time I want to disable that key. How can do that?

```
$(document).on (‘keydown’ , function (e){
var userVal = e.which ∥ e.keycode
valadation (userVal)

})

function valadation (userVal){
if (37 == userVal){
alert (“Wecome”)
 }
}
```

Comment: Disable what key? `37` isn't a key...? Do you mean keyCode 37?

Comment: how can you press 37? do you mean on keyup?

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable and update its value.

```js
let clickVar = 0
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {

  var userVal = e.which || e.keycode
  valadation(userVal)

})

function valadation(userVal) {

  if (37 === userVal && clickVar === 0) {
    alert('Welcome');
    clickVar++
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro!! It's working fine right now. I was training past 2 days so finally I got it right now.

Comment: Can you explaing how does clickVar  variable working.

Answer (score 0):

```js
                                        //name the handler
$(document.body).on('keydown', function alertOnEnter (e) {
  if ([e.keyCode, e.which].indexOf(13) > -1) {
                     //remove the handler from the event
    $(document.body).off('keydown', alertOnEnter);
    alert('you hit enter');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```